# blank spaces in a new line

Tags: spacing, line-spacing

I want to add some blank spaces to my margin when i go to a new line.
The second " = " sign should be just below the first " = "
How can i do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for environments provided in the `amsmath` package.  Here, I use `aligned` to make certain tab-points align at the `&` tokens.  In this case, the equations are not numbered.  If you need numbering, use the `align` environment without the surrounding `\[...\]` delimiters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
f(n) &= \log(n^n)^3\\
     &= \log(n^{3n})
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]